# R dplyr error Problem with mutate - Trying to group by two columns and mutate new column with a percentage

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to create a geom_col where I get to see the avg. sell rate by a category + gender.
For this, I'm trying to first group_by Category and Gender and then saving two vars via Summarise followed by creating a new column in mutate  function, which I'd like to use in my ggplot (Geom_col for CATEGORY and facet wrap for Gender)

Here is my error:
Error: Problem with `summarise()` input `total_qty`.
x invalid 'type' (list) of argument
i Input `total_qty` is `sum(qty_sold)`.

Edit: Added sample data as img.
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Can anyone help with this, pls.

```
enter code here
data %>% 
group_by(CATEGORY, Gender) %>%
summarise(total_qty = sum(qty_sold)) %>%
summarise(total_qty_avail = sum(`Qty Received`)) %>%
ungroup %>%
mutate(sell_rate=total_qty/total_qty_avail)%>%
ggplot(data=data,aes(x=CATEGORY,y=sell_rate))+
geom_col() +
facet_wrap(~Gender)
```

Dput structure

```
 structure(list(CATEGORY = c("A", "A", "B"), Gender = c("M", "F", 
    "M"), `Qty Received` = c(100, 150, 50), qty_sold = c(10, 20, 
    5)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
    ))
```

Comment: Or you can use `mutate` instead of `summarise` to refer to column you have just created.

Comment: Please use `dput` to show the example so that we get the structure.  Images wouldn't get us understand the structure i..e. `dput(droplevels(head(data)))`

Comment: example data created using code such as `data <- tibble(category = c("A", "A"), Gender = c("M", "F"))` would be much more convenient for the people helping you out, rather than an image. Or, `dput` as suggested.

Comment: @Damian thanks, I've added dput now

Comment: One more request to make sure we're on the same page.  What output did you expect based on the input data?

Comment: @Damian that it would show average qty sold per Category and gender

Comment: Based on the example data, what quantities would you expect? For example what should the answer be for category "A" and gender "M"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After the first `summarise` statement, the only columns available are the grouping columns and the 'total_qty'.  If we need to create the 'total_qty_avail', do it in the first `summarise`

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
 group_by(CATEGORY, Gender) %>%
 summarise(total_qty = sum(qty_sold, na.rm = TRUE),
          total_qty_avail = sum(`Qty Received`, na.rm = TRUE), .groups = 'drop')
```

---

If the OP wanted to create the 'total_qty_avail' grouped by only 'CATEGORY' (assuming that the OP was aware of the `summarise` dropping the last grouping column, then instead do a grouping by 'CATEGORY', followed by a second grouping with the `sum` of 'Qty Received' and 'Gender' added as new grouping columns

```
data %>%
     group_by(CATEGORY) %>%
     group_by(total_qty_avail = sum(`Qty Received`, na.rm = TRUE),
              Gender, .add = TRUE) %>%
     summarise(total_qty = sum(qty_sold, na.rm = TRUE), .groups = 'drop')
```

---

Regarding the specific error, it could be because the `summarise`d column is `list` e.g. if we create a `list` column with `iris` and do the group by summarise, it returns the same error

```
iris %>% 
    mutate(Sepal.Length = list(Sepal.Length)) %>% 
    group_by(Species) %>% 
    summarise(total = sum(Sepal.Length))
```

> Error: Problem with `summarise()` input `total`.
> ✖ invalid 'type' (list) of argument
> ℹ Input `total` is `sum(Sepal.Length)`.
> ℹ The error occurred in group 1: Species = "setosa".
> Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

An option would be to `unlist` the list column to a `vector`

```
data %>% 
 mutate(qty_sold = unlist(qty_sold)) %>%
 group_by(CATEGORY, Gender) %>%
 summarise(total_qty = sum(qty_sold, na.rm = TRUE),
          total_qty_avail = sum(`Qty Received`, na.rm = TRUE), .groups = 'drop')
```

---

There is also another issue in the `ggplot` call.   As it is already in chain (`%>%`), the `data` would be `.` and not the original `data` (also, the data argument is not needed)

```
data %>% 
 group_by(CATEGORY, Gender) %>%
 summarise(total_qty = sum(qty_sold, na.rm = TRUE),
          total_qty_avail = sum(`Qty Received`, na.rm = TRUE), 
            .groups = 'drop') %>%  
  mutate(sell_rate=total_qty/total_qty_avail) %>%   
  ggplot(data=., aes(x = CATEGORY, y = sell_rate)) +
    geom_col() +
    facet_wrap(~Gender)
```

-output

[image]

Comment: hmmm tried both. Still getting the same error. I wonder where I'm going wrong with this. Both my group_by are for Factor variables as well.

Comment: @AdilK Can you check the `str(data)`.  Is there a `list` column?

Comment: @AdilK Try `data %>% unnest(c(qty_sold)) %>% group_by(CATEGORY, Gender) %>%summarise(total_qty = sum(qty_sold, na.rm = TRUE),
          total_qty_avail = sum(`Qty Received`, na.rm = TRUE), .groups = 'drop')`

Comment: this is now giving : Error: Must subset columns with a valid subscript vector.
x Subscript has the wrong type `gg/ggplot`.
i It must be numeric or character.

Comment: i have now added a sample data

Comment: @AdilK can you use `dput` instead of images.  This is to understand the structure of the data

Comment: thanks, have added dput now in the original code

Comment: @AdilK With that example, the last code block in my post is working

Comment: thanks, I genuinely don't know what's wrong here. When I try the same code with my original data, I'm getting this error. I'll try n relook at the whole thing again tom morning.Error: Problem with `summarise()` input `total_qty`.
x invalid 'type' (list) of argument
i Input `total_qty` is `sum(qty_sold, na.rm = TRUE)`.
i The error occurred in group 1: CATEGORY = "A", Gender = "MALE".

Comment: @AdilK Do you have `plyr` package loaded as well.  I would use `dplyr::summarise` if the function is masked